# syscall variables undefined

Tags: go, system-calls

When trying to build the following program on my Mac I get a build error: `undefined: syscall.TCPInfo` even though that variable is clearly documented http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#TCPInfo

```
package main

import "syscall"

func main() {
    _ = syscall.TCPInfo{}
}
```

Here is my go tool version.

```
$ go version
go version go1.3 darwin/amd64
```

I thought this might be an issue a lack of OS support so I tried it on http://play.golang.org, but it looks like many documented variables are just randomly missing from the `syscall` package: http://play.golang.org/p/w3Uk6NaZVy

Am I missing something?

Comment: The syscall package is platform dependent. The online docs are only showing the linux build.

Comment: and GOOS on play.golang.org isn't linux either, it's running under nacl.

Comment: blah, yeah that was it. thanks

Answer (score 10):

The variable specified inside syscall are OS dependent.

you can add a suffix to the file to specify which os they should be built for:

```
// +build linux,386 darwin,!cgo
```

So you can use specific `syscall` flags for each OS.